# NIFI - Processing HDFS Data

Tags: apache-nifi

I am new to the tool. I have a requirement to read data from HDFS and filter some entries and transfor some fields and write the output to unix local system. Could you let me know the components I can please.

I am using ListHDFS, FetchHDFS, updateattributes but after that little struck what component to use to convert hdfs 'lzo' data and how to transform.

Please could you help me on it.

Thanks,
Kumar

Comment: So you want to decompress a lzo file? Have a look at compressContent processor (in Decompress mode), if it doesn't do the job, you have to use an executeScript.

Comment: Thanks alot. Could you let me know what "compression Format" I should use for lzo files please. Will it be lzma format

Comment: Give a try with lzma, but not sure it will works. On your FetchHDFS you should have a property named compressioncodec, where you can choose LZO, let me know if this works.